# Allow to use URL shorteners within error messages

Tags: feature-request, url-shortener

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64704998/runtime-error-while-running-simple-import-due-to-numpy-installation) I have a runtime error, but the error message contains a shortened URL. While trying to ask a question, I was forced to replace that shortened URL by the real URL, despite writing the shortened within a code block, where it wouldn't be clickable:

> [image]

Apparently shortened URLs are some security hazard, so I do understand that Stack Overflow community wants to protect itself, but blocking the possibility to show error messages for one of the major programming languages is really not the way to go. When asking for help, it is crucial to put the error message as complete and as exact as possible, so other people can search for it, therefore copy-paste is heavily advised.

As a counter-proposal I would suggest only to allow shortened URLs in code blocks or other formatting, or not to allow shortened URLs as URLs (they are not clickable).

[url-shortener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/url-shortener) says that "*the use of URL shorteners on Stack Overflow, which is (except for a few cases) disabled*". Does this mean that there are means to enable the use of shortened URLs, e.g. in code-blocks?

Are there any plans in this direction?

Comment: Not sure what the exceptional cases are. Here is the MSE canonical on the subject: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/289658/158100 which does say *I have no desire to handle a lot of complaints about this* ...

Comment: The URL appears to be in a code block anyway, was that the case when the system said you couldn't post it? Also note that you're not writing a thriller here; if you know people are going to wonder what on earth you're talking about, fix it to tell them.

Comment: Huh, I thought you could post short-links in code blocks. Apparently you can't.

Comment: Does Python really use shortened URLs in its error messages? Wow. Another thing I can add to my list...

Comment: @rene: indeed: images of error messages are forbidden, but shortened URLs are forbidden too. So, the only way to show a shortened URL in an error message, is by using an image.

Comment: @rene He probably has *even less* desire to handle complaints now that he's not getting paid to do it, eh?

Comment: @CodyGray I didn't want to make that grim joke, but yeah.

Comment: @CodyGray That is a custom error message of a third-party library (albeit a very prominent one).

Comment: This proposal would be a lot more convincing if the purpose of the tinyurl weren't to allow *you* to fix the issue *yourself*. This is not an error to post in [so], it is an error to just read thoroughly.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I see. So this bug report is filed in the wrong place. The real bug is that a library uses a URL shortener in its error messages. Can you direct Dominique to where is the correct place is to file that bug?

Comment: @CodyGray: thanks for the quick responses. In the meantime I've followed a comment on my original question, which solved my original question, so the urgency of my problem is hereby heavily reduced. Still leaves the question I've raised here: please find a way to allow shortened URLs in code-blocks, so that people, in future, are able to mentioned exact error messages while asking questions on the Stackoverflow website.

Comment: I'm personally not interested in doing that at all. There is no compelling reason for posting shortened URLs on this site. You seem to be arguing that we should make exceptions in certain cases to allow them simply because they appear in error messages, but if I released a library that included pornographic images in its error messages, should we also make an exception to allow those to be posted on Stack Overflow? I vote no.

Comment: Do you expect Python, or any other popular programmong language, to put references to pornogtaphic sites in their error messages?

Comment: @Dominique - I think this was a grotesque trope. The real issue occurs when someone posts this code on SO - there is no way to know upfront if the link is valid or spam if we allow shortened URLs to be posted anywhere. I don't think we should cater to quarks of error messages (really, shortened URLs in error messages??). The only real use for shortened URLs would be in comments, but that use case is subject to the same problem (and could be better mitigated by rediscussing comment size limits). P.s. Why should anyone be deprived of a clear indication of where the link is going to take them?

Comment: @Dominique - no need to get wound up :) [Trope](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/trope). The question conveys surprise, not a genuine query of whether error messages can contain short links. Anyways, this is beyond the point - why do you think it is *better* to allow short URLs than preventing spammy or unreadable links? if the link is *really* relevant for understanding, post the original *long* one separately and actually make it clickable - if you simply follow the "post error messages as is" rule, then this is a clear case of valuing the book of law over its spirit.

Comment: Without diving into the specifics of this error message or whether libraries should or shouldn't do this, the point still stands that code blocks having unexpected illegal character sequences is jarring from a UX perspective, especially when you're just copying and pasting it from output. This is a bit of a weird edge case for the no shorteners rule.

Answer (score 6):

I don’t see a compelling reason to change the way the system works.

Just take the shortened URL, paste it into a browser, and copy the full URL into the question. (Because you’re not quoting this part exactly I would write something like “the error links to *X*” under your code block containing the error.)